# How to go back to the beginning of a loop in python if error?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to go to the start of a 'for' loop if some error comes out in python like this.

```
for i in ~:
   try:
      ---code---
   except ~Error:
      # go back to the beginning of loop
      # do the next thing
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you looking for `pass` or `continue`?

Comment: The continue statement in Python returns the control to the beginning of the while loop

Comment: wouldnt this create a continual loop, making it to the error and restarting every time?

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the for loop within a while loop.

```
while condition:
    for index in iterable:
        try:
            --code--
        except Exception:
             break
```

Comment: Would be good if the condition contained a maximum number of repetitions allowed, otherwise you could end up with an infinite loop. Also I would add a statement after the for loop to explicitly set the condition to False so that if the loop is successful, the while loop is stopped. Anyway I believe your code is the only solution.

Comment: Yes. As Luca said,  you'd have to ensure the while condition was adequate enough to prevent an infinite loop. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should check out the `while` statement.

For example:

```
i=1
while i < n:
    if something:
       do something
       i += 1
    else: 
       do something else  
       i = 2 #loop restart
```

There you have two options to do something and also the "loop restart"

Also you can try with `continue`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do what you are asking in Python (if I understood correctly). That being said, to emulate that functionality, I would suggest using a `while` loop and a `continue` statement before incrementing the indexing variable.

Something like this:

```
some_number = 10 # any number
i = 0
while i < some_number:
    try:
        do_something(i) # might err
    except:
        continue
    i += 1
```